# Any ideas for a tag to capture solutions built on top of Monero?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that there's no appropriate tag for [this kind of question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/can-new-platform-cryptocurrency-can-be-build-on-top-of-monero). Any ideas? It could capture these tie-ins using tx_extra, lightning-type or other tier 2 solutions etc. It's not really sidechains (existing tag) but should be a wider scope tag.

how about monero-level-2, or just keep it under scaling?

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain of the best solution but we seem to have at least 4 tags that at least touch on the areas you mention above. I don't like `monero-level-2` because I think it will lack a clear meaning for many users of this stack.

```
tx-extra
```

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tx-extra

```
scaling
```

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling

```
side-chain
```

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/side-chain

```
lightning-network
```

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-network

Comment: I don't like it either, but just used it as an example. Maybe monero-solutions ?

Comment: @JollyMort monero-solutions does not seek like a tag someone would use when searching for those kind of questions either. How about something like second-tier-network?

Comment: Getting closer now, how about just second-tier ? Or monero-second-tier. Tag guidance: anything built on top of monero network (worded in a nicer way)

Comment: @JollyMort I like the sound of that but lets wait to here feedback from more people before making any final decisions. We don't have a large number of questions yet so re-tagging if needed should not take too long.